# Отправка формы по enter

Tags: javascript

Скажите, как сделать сабмит формы по нажатию в textarea кнопки enter? но если нажаты enter+shift, то перенос стоки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
<textarea 
    onkeypress="if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==13) {/* действия для  SHIFT+Enter */} else if(!event.shiftKey && event.keyCode==13) {/* действия для Enter */}">
```

Comment: hello from India? :)
    
    if( isEnter && isShift ) {}
    else if( isEnter && !isShift ) {} // wtf?

    if( isEnter ) {
      if( isShift ) {}
      else {}
    }

Comment: как вариант:

    isEnter && (isShift && console.log(1), !isShift) && console.log(2);

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
txt.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Shift + Enter');
        // Вместо алерта - ваш код
    }
    return true;
}
```